# Need to port complex GUI interface projects from RAD Studio to Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, porting, rad-studio

I'm working for a company which maintain several Desktop application projects written in C++. All of these apps have complex GUI interfaces. What I mean by "complex" is, among others, interfaces with many components, deep component hierarchy, usage of frames, third party and/or custom component packages which support features like transparency and animation.

Until now we always used the Embarcadero RAD Studio suite to write and maintain our apps. However the many recurring bugs of each new version has tired my superiors, and now they are considering the possibility to migrate to Visual Studio.

I think that migrate the application core functions written in c++ will not be a real issue.

However for the GUI it's an other story. I had a previous experience with complex interfaces under the Visual Studio 2003 compiler, and I remember that this was a painful work to create and maintain them. There was no real designer, components were limited, and a huge part of the job was to be done manually. From that I took a look on the designing tools provided with Visual Studio 2017, and my first impression is that not much has changed since. The designer for c++ projects is still so rudimentary, especially in comparison to the RAD Studio VCL, with its well-supplied component library. The C# API is closer than what I need, but I cannot envisage to rewrite all my code in C# as a serious option.

I tried to search tutorials about the good practices to apply in a such situation, but until now I found no helpful info.

My questions are:

1. Can I recover my current GUI interface, at least a part of it, while I migrate to Visual Studio, or do I have to plan to rewrite everything from scratch?
2. Does Visual Studio provide a mechanism similar to VCL for composing GUI interfaces, installing third parties packages and writing custom components? And if yes, where can I find relevant info about that?
3. Is a such port possible without a high dose of headache and tears? Where can I found relevant info about a such process?

Answer (score 4):

I am also currently working on a product which is developed using Embarcadero RAD Studio and some 3rd party UI controls. Development was done many years back, so its UI is quite older style. I tried to migrate it in Visual Studio, by developing application logic in C++ and UI in C#(WPF). But it is as good as writing new application, cost is more. So we discontinued that exercise. However what I learned during this is –

1. Migrating VCL application from RAD Studio to Visual Studio is like writing new application. There is no one-to-one mapping(data types, stuctures, UI controls etc), you have start from scratch. Also there are no tools available which can help this migration.
2. Some data types, data structures, UI controls are easily available in RAD Studio, which are not available in Visual C++ (MFC), and vice versa. So you have to review every code line while migrating the application logic.
3. There are no 3rd party UI controls available for Visual C++(MFC) which can make your life easy. For RAD Studio you have LMD tools, businessSkinForms etc.
4. After working on RAD Studio over 5+ years, Developing UI is quite easy in RAD Studio (UI in C++). However in Visual Studio you can develop your UI in C#(WPF) which will be rich and can communicate with application logic written in C++.

As you said, you have several desktop applications developed with RAD Studio, while migrating to Visual Studio start with smaller and standalone application. So you will get some confidence during migration of this application and then you can put such migrated small application in production one by one without impact.

~Nilesh

Comment: Thank you to share your experience, it's really useful for me. It's unfortunately what I suspected. I saw that it was possible to use the C++ CLI to at least have a real designer (which is the C# designer in this case), but that still remains highly restrictive when you come from the RAD Studio API. Fortunately we had planned this type of scenario by writing a code that is as portable as possible, and corss-platform. My company envisage until the possibility to write our own designer for Visual Studio. I will give news about it here if I can over time.